# To debug webapp, do I need to run tomcat/tc server in debugging mode?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, tomcat

I'm newbie in java development. In visual studio c++, we just run our application in debug mode.

but in Java/eclipse, it seems we must run both our webapp and tomcat in debugging mode. is it?

if run tomcat in debugging mode is just an option, then what benifit if the tomcat be running in debugging mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't run a web app on its own, you run it from within Tomcat.  If you have downloaded the "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers" flavor from http://eclipse.org/downloads/ (which you should have if you are developing web applications), you would configure Tomcat from within Eclipse and start Tomcat using the debug mode button under the Servers view.

Running Tomcat with the debugging parameters such as Miron suggested would allow you to attach a debugging session to Tomcat instance running outside of Eclipse, or even on a remote box.

You do not have to start Tomcat in debug mode, just like you do not have to start your .NET application in debug mode.  You will not have access to breakpoints if you simply Run the application.

Comment: Now, I know that webapp runs in tomcat process, so that process need to open it's debug mode to allow debug client to communicate, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Good thing is that there is no "debug" mode for webapp - you need to run tomcat with debug params (JAVA_OPTS).

here they are:

```
-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n
```

they are specified (and commented out probably) in your config file in tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

If you are starting tomcat from within eclipse it is just a case of using the debug rather than start option from the servers view in eclipse when running up tomcat this should then allow your application to stop at breakpoints.